# Clearing a textbox when clicked in actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, textbox

I've got an array of multiple textboxes that will be used for entering information. However I made this function that should clear them all whenever they're clicked yet it says that the object I entered into the parameters==null.

```
var arrange:Array=new Array(TB1,TB2,TB3,TB4,TB5);

function focuser(ityou:Object):void {
    trace(ityou)
        ityou.text="";  
}

for (var i=0;i<arrange.length;i++) {
    arrange[i].addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,function(event:FocusEvent):void { focuser(arrange[i]) });
}
```

I don't know if you can enter functions inside .addEventListener like in Lua but, I tried :P

Comment: Just a 'by the way' - have you seen the flexlib promptingTextInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this on for size.

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.FocusEvent;

var arrange:Array = [tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5];


function focuser(e:FocusEvent):void {
    trace(e.target)
        e.target.text = "";
}

for each(var t:TextField in arrange)
{
    t.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, focuser);

}
```

Comment: obviously change TextField to TextBox or TextArea or whatever your text boxes are.

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue if it's a TextField, but if we're talking about a component, event.currentTarget might be needed here instead of event.target. I seem to remember that FocusEvents bubble. event.target could refer to something inside the component, if there are children.